# How to pass context from wizard to view. Odoo 13

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In the wizard I added a field `product_id`, and button.
When choosing the product and clicking on button I want to get the `stock.quant` tree view of the product.
How to pass value in context ?

```
class Wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard.wizard'

product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Product")

 @api.model
 def my_button(self):
    return {
        'name': _('Products'),
        'view_type': 'tree',
        'view_mode': 'list',
        'res_model': 'stock.quant',
        'context': {},
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`self` represent current recordset. We can pass value with `self.product_id`

For example:

```
"context": {"default_product_id": self.product_id.id, 
            "search_default_product_id": self.product_id.id},
```

Comment: I tried with : 'context': {'active_id': self.product_id.id},  but I still not having the correct result.

Comment: It's not `active_id`. It's `default_product_id`. `active_id` is a database ID of record. In your case, it says `stock.quant`. So that is wrong.

Comment: when trying "context": {"default_product_id": self.product_id.id}I got all list , not the selected one ; even I added self.ensure_one() in the function 'my_button'.

Comment: I have updated my answer. In that case, we need to also include "search_default_product_id" key.